# Importing contributions always imports $0 in Amount

Tags: import, contributions

I am having a really weird problem importing Contributions.

**Background**: I am exporting data from my Drupal-Civicrm site and importing it into our new Wordpress-civicrm site. I do not want to go thru the database route because I bumped into too many issues and the civicrm became very unstable. Hence I have created wordpress-civicrm instance from scratch and I am importing data from the GUI. So far contacts and memberships have been imported successfully.

**Problem**: Now that I am importing the contributions, no matter how I setup the import the Amount is imported as $0 (even though I can clearly see in the import wizard that it is a non-zero amount). I even tried to map the Net Amount field and the Fee Amount field correctly. Yet the Total amount is always getting imported as $0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you importing as $5 or just as 5? Have you done an export to see how they data is held as this often provides a clue as to how the data needs to be structured to import. Also be aware that there is a very helpful extension that extends what was possible with GUI imports. 
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport

Comment: I am importing them as $. I am really not understanding why this is failing. Here is the example of my csv record : "Donor Name","First Name","Contact ID","Donor Email","Donor Phone","Financial Type","Source","Payment Type","Transaction ID","Date Received","Receipt Date","Amount","Fee Amount","Net Amount","Country"
"xxxxxx, xxxx","xxxx","924","xxxxxxx@xxxx.com","xxx-xxx-xxxx","Member Dues","Online Contribution: Sustaining Membership","Credit Card","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","2016-09-16 00:00","2016-09-16 20:48","$ 15.00","$ 0.00","$ 15.00","United States"

Comment: O boy! I change the "$ 15.00" to "15.00" and bingo, it worked. I feel so stupid now I wasted more than an hour this! Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Check how you are importing your data. It is often worth doing an export to see how they data is held as this often provides a clue as to how the data needs to be structured to import.

For example you may be importing as 5 when it expects $5 or vice versa.

Also be aware that there is a very helpful extension that extends what was possible with GUI imports. github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport

Comment: See above - there should be no currency symbol.